# Selecting nth element using xpath is returning more results then expected

Tags: html, xpath

I'm using the following query:

`//*[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " sub-category-wrap ")][1]/dl/dt`

This should select the first `.sub-category-wrap` and return it's `/dl/dt` content. Ideally, this would be:

- `Yarn`
- `Mice`

For some reason, it returns:

- `Yarn`
- `Mice`
- `Fast Tires`
- `Fancy Paint`

So for some reason, it's grabbing the content from the `dt`'s in both `.clear-wrap` elements. I can't seem to get it to select the `dt`'s from the nth `.sub-category-wrap`.

**Note:** The `[1]` selector in the xpath query is actually a variable in my code, so keep that mind in the solutions you present.

```
<div class="clear-wrap">
      <div class="sub-category-wrap">
        <h3>Cats</h3>
        <dl>      
          <dt>Yarn</dt>
            <dd><!-- Content --> </dd>
          <dt>Mice</dt>
          <dd><!-- Content --></dd>
        </dl>
      </div>
    <div class="sub-category-wrap">
        <h3>Dogs</h3>
        <dl>      
          <dt>Kibbles</dt>
            <dd><!-- Content --> </dd>
          <dt>Drool</dt>
          <dd><!-- Content --></dd>
        </dl>
      </div>
 </div>
 <div class="clear-wrap">
      <div class="sub-category-wrap">
        <h3>Cars</h3>
        <dl>      
          <dt>Fast Tires</dt>
            <dd><!-- Content --> </dd>
          <dt>Fancy Paint</dt>
          <dd><!-- Content --></dd>
        </dl>
      </div>
    <div class="sub-category-wrap">
        <h3>Trucks</h3>
        <dl>      
          <dt>Mud Tires</dt>
            <dd><!-- Content --> </dd>
          <dt>Loud Pipes</dt>
          <dd><!-- Content --></dd>
        </dl>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Just as a clarification, what should the results of `//*[contains(..)][2]` and `//*[contains(..)][3]` be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your query was doing was checking that the element was a first child, not that it was the first of the result node-set. This should work as intended:

```
(//div[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " sub-category-wrap ")])[1]/dl/dt
```

Answer (score 2):

The query `//x[1]` means `/descendant-or-self::node()/child::x[1]`, which selects the first x child of every element in the document. What you want is `(//x)[1]` which selects the first node in the sequence selected by `//x`.

Comment: Whilst the currently accepted answer solved the particular issue the OP was having.  This answer more clearly explains the underlying confusion and the appropriate solution in general terms.